# How to properly clear TextField on submit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I want to log some text and clear the `TextField` after submitting without changing the value of the logged text. How I can achieve that?

Here's example of my code:

```
@State private var loggedText: String = ""
@State private var showLoggedText = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        if showLoggedText {
            Text(loggedText)
        }
            
            HStack {
                TextField(
                       "Add new set",
                       text: $loggedText
                   )
                .onSubmit {
                    showLoggedText = true
                    loggedText = ""
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You need to assign the value of loggedText to another property. On Submit you override the value with an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off one of the comments. It seems as though that you need to assign `loggedText` to another variable like so:

```
@State private var loggedText: String = ""
@State private var showLoggedText = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        if showLoggedText {
            Text(loggedText)
        }
            
            HStack {
                TextField(
                       "Add new set",
                       text: $loggedText
                   )
                .onSubmit {
                    showLoggedText = true
                    newText = loggedText
                }
            }
    }
```

This will allow you to submit the text without it being cleared. The  `loggedText = ""` clears everything that you had. Keep in mind that this code won't "lock" whatever's in loggedText. If you change the field after submitting. The text will be updated again.